# Is the keyword "ALIAS" actually used?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sql-standard, reserved-word

According to PostgreSQL 7.1 through 9.1 (now unsupported), `ALIAS` is listed as a reserved word, at least for SQL-99. Later versions do not show it - suggesting that it has been dropped as a reserved word. The old PostgreSQL docs do say *"the presence of a key word does not indicate the existence of a feature."* When aliasing a table or column I've seen `AS`, but never `ALIAS`.

Where is (or was) the SQL keyword `ALIAS` used? Was it ever in-use or only ever reserved for future-use?

Answer (score 16):

[PostgreSQL maintains a list of reserved **and** non-reserved terms in the appendix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-keywords-appendix.html). `ALIAS` is absent from that list. You can verify PostgreSQL does not use `ALIAS` by checking out the [YACC grammar](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/97c39498e5ca9208d3de5a443a2282923619bf91/src/backend/parser/gram.y). Even as far back as [Postgres95 `ALIAS` was not a reserved word (the first version in the migration from QUEL to SQL)](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/d31084e9d1118b25fd16580d9d8c2924b5740dff/src/backend/parser/keywords.c)

- [MySQL does **NOT** reserve `ALIAS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-in-current-series)
- [MariaDB does **NOT** reserve `ALIAS`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/)
- [Oracle does **NOT** reserve `ALIAS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)
- [SQL Server **does** (in T-SQL) reserve `ALIAS` (as a potential future keyword on their "reserved keyword" list)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

## SQL Standard

- In SQL-92, `ALIAS` was marked as a `<reserved word>`; but, there was no use assigned for that `<reserved word>`.
- In SQL-99 `ALIAS` was marked as an "Additional Reserved Word", and added to the list of `<reserved word>`; but, there was no use assigned for that `<reserved word>`. Perhaps they reserved the term with the intent to define meaning later, and then withdrew it at a different point. Or, perhaps they reserved the term for vendor defined implementation. PostgreSQL reflected the spec's reservation in the docs, and then removed that reservation with the spec.
- In SQL-2011, `ALIAS` is no where to be found and the word "alias" only appears in reference to *'Feature T053, “Explicit aliases for all-fields reference”'*

*ℹ There is no digitized copy of [SQL-86](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/168595/2639), or [SQL-89](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/205482/2639)*

Answer (score 8):

It is used at least in various flavours of Db2: [`ALIAS`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000910.html) is an object that allows you to specify a different name for another object, like table. It's frequently used to allow references in one schema to objects in another schema without explicitly specifying that schema.

```
create table SOMEOTHERSCHEMA.FOOBAR (...);
set schema MYSCHEMA;
create alias FOOBAR for SOMEOTHERSCHEMA.FOOBAR;
select * from FOOBAR;
```

`ALIAS` is an alias for `SYNONYM`; the latter concept also exists in Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: *`ALIAS` is an alias for `SYNONYM`* – hmm, I guess you could also say `ALIAS` is a synonym of `SYNONYM`...

Comment: @AndriyM It's the other way around: [`SYNONYM` is a synonym for `ALIAS`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0054583.html), [though not always](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_aliasandsynonym.html).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a place where the keyword `ALIAS` is used in all versions of PostgreSQL.

Not in SQL, though, like [Evan clearly documented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227101/3684). But in the [procedural language PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ALIAS) to create aliases for parameters or variables.

It was more commonly used before Postgres 8.0 while named parameters were not yet supported for PL/pgSQL functions. Since then, only few use cases are left. [The manual concludes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ALIAS)

> It's best to use it only for the purpose of overriding predetermined names.