# What is the status of the PostQUEL source code?

Tags: postgresql

Recently as part of my answer to [*"Is the keyword “ALIAS” actually used?"*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227101/2639) I wanted to go back further than Postgres95. Postgres95 is the first version of Postgres that was migrated to use SQL rather than QUEL.

Is POSTQUEL (the version that used [QUEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUEL_query_languages)) open source and is it available anywhere? The PostgreSQL repo starts with an import of Postgres95.

Comment: This is not an off-topic question. It mightn't be of interest to you personally, and might be asking about older code (as Joel Spolsky says, code doesn't rust!) but that does **not** make it off-topic. I just wish whoever flagged it as such had the courage of their convictions and put in a comment as to why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database was not known as `POSTQUEL`, but as `POSTGRES`. PostQUEL is "an incompatible, extended version of QUEL (the Ingres query language)."

As to the source code, I found it linked from this [Command Prompt Blog Post](https://www.commandprompt.com/blog/the_old_berkeley_postgres_code/),

You can find it available on the [POSTGRES Project page at Berkeley](http://db.cs.berkeley.edu/postgres.html).